# Making Excel calculate an equasion with four unknown variables

Tags: excel, statistics, combinatorics, vba

I'm sitting on this for one and a half weeks and I'm just missing the deciding hint. No need to spoon-feed me, of course, if the solution is too obvious. I have two variables **A** and **B** which I know in every occasion (*A: number of workers, B: number of factories*). **C** is quick to calculate, it is **A / B = C**, or the average of workers per factory. For one certain year, I have the distribution of workers among four different size classes of factories, which I want to project onto the other data sets.

This leaves me with **(A1+A2+A3+A4) / (B1+B2+B3+B4) = C** and **A1 / B1 = C1** and so on. To be able to pull this through, I have to assume that **C1** to **C4** stay the same (**77, 206, 663, 1555**) or within a certain deviation range. This means that **A1 = 77*B1** and so on, which leaves me with just four unknown variables instead of twelve.

At this point I have set up a table in Excel which works perfectly as long as I know **B1** to **B4** (which I do only for this exact year). The goal is to make Excel find them out according to several parameters but alas, I don't know exactly how to translate them for Excel. I've played around with VBA which I expect has the solution but its language confuses the crap out of me.

The upper table shows how it should look like in the end. The lower table is the actual, programmed one. The green pieces are programmed, the white cells are constants, the red bits are what gives me headaches.
[image: The upper table shows how it should look like in the end. The lower table is the actual, programmed one. The green pieces are programmed, the white cells are constants, the red bits are what gives me headaches.] The actual equation that I need to solve is:

**77*B1 + 206*B2 + 663*B3 + 1555*B4 = 98200 if B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 = 482** (of course I would need to take the unrounded numbers because the variables must be integers; the variables are not Excel coordinates). My thesis is that there is only one possible combination and if it's not, I want to know how many more there are.

The if-part is one of the paramaters that I'd like to give Excel. The others are:
**B1 > B2 > B3 > B4** and, if it's necessary, (in Excel coordinates), **F11 = 1** and **F13 = 1**. I especially despair at the task to make it behave according to the *bigger than*-presumption. So far, I could very slightly adapt this code that I copied from another thread but this is just a small step.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim NewValue As Double
Dim ControlRange1 As Range
Dim Item As Range
Set ControlRange1 = Range("B12:E12")

If Not Intersect(ControlRange1, Target) Is Nothing Then
'The change occured in one of the cells we want to control

NewValue = (Range("F12").Value - Target.Value) / 4
For Each Item In ControlRange1
    If Not Item.Address = Target.Address Then ' Don't change the cell that was changed
        Item.Value = NewValue
    End If
Next
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Set ControlRange1 = Nothing
Set ControlRange2 = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Take the sum (or product.. whatever)  of b12 to e12 as an objective (max or min) and set b12 to e12 as changing cells (integer if suitable), set other cells as constraints and solve...

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183650/4961700

Comment: Thank you!!! I probably would have solved that days ago if I knew that the solver is still in Excel and you just need to activate it in some back alley menu :D
Now that it gives me the exact perfect numbers, the last step is to make the table actually useful for my research and allow Excel to make ~5% deviations from C1 to C4 (B14:E14) in such a manner that B12:E12 are still integers. Or is messing with the constraint precision equivalent to this? If so, it might be good to know how many possible solutions there are per percentage of deviation to draw a probability curve.